# cvxopt installation on windows 7/64bit

Tags: gcc, mingw, pip, cvxopt

I'm trying to install cvxopt package on python 3.4. I'm using pip but I get the error message "command 'c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1"

I tried numerous stuff like installing numpy+mkl which is not running as well I don't know why, or installing atlas but none of those helps resolve my problem so I'm stuck. Should I install atlas or something else ?

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to install a binary instead: `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`. Note that if you want to compile from the source we need more information about `gcc`'s error. `exit status 1` only means that something failed. With that little information it's probably not possible to provide helpful answers.

Comment: The exact error message I get is "command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1". I also tried to install a binary as you recommend me but its installation is not working correctly either..