# python 3.5 - cannot use cvxopt

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, cvxopt

Trying to use cvxopt with Anaconda.

Followed installation instruction here: [How to install cvxopt for Python 3.5 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431556/how-to-install-cvxopt-for-python-3-5-on-windows-7)

But got the error:

```
import cvxopt

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>

import cvxopt.base

ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

Also tried to install `numpy-mkl`, but also got error `"No matching distribution found for numpy-mkl"`

I don't seem to find `cvxopt.base` or `pyd` in the `site-package` folder though. What to do next please?

Environment: Windows 7 64 bit; conda 4.3.22 (python 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by following below: 
[import cvxopt.base: the specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778178/import-cvxopt-base-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Reinstalled numpy and cvxopt from:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

It seems the cvxopt installation mentioned here causes some problems on my machine (unknown version number):
[How to install cvxopt for Python 3.5 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431556/how-to-install-cvxopt-for-python-3-5-on-windows-7)